# ¿Que pasa con la referencia al objeto?

Tags: java

Mi intención era crear un `JForm` en el cual jugar al gato, cada que se gane guardar ese `JForm` en una lista, al final de cierto número de juegos ganados (4 en este código) mostrar las ventanas que guarde en la lista donde se aprecia como se gano el juego y si fue con X ó O.

El problema es que si hace lo que quiero, pero no logro entender que sucede internamente en el objeto y la referencia a este. En el método `checkForWin()` le paso a la lista la referencia al objeto mediante `this` y funciona correctamente, a diferencia de cuando en lugar de `this` le paso la referencia a `otro`.

```
else {
        TicTacCollection.gatos.add(otro);
```

`otro` es un objeto de la misma clase instanciado dentro de esta en el método `setMarca()` como se ve en el siguiente código.

public class Tablero extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public JButton[][] board;
private char currentPlayerMark;
Tablero otro;

public Tablero() {

    board = new JButton[3][3];
    currentPlayerMark = 'X';
    initComponents();
    initializeBoard();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

private void initializeBoard() {
    board[0][0] = b1;
    board[0][1] = b2;
    board[0][2] = b3;
    board[1][0] = b4;
    board[1][1] = b5;
    board[1][2] = b6;
    board[2][0] = b7;
    board[2][1] = b8;
    board[2][2] = b9;
}

private void reset(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            board[i][j].setText("");
        }
    }
}

public boolean isBoardFull() {
    boolean isFull = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[i][j].getText().equals("")) {
                isFull = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return isFull;
}

public boolean checkForWin() {
    boolean winner = (checkRowsForWin() || checkColumnsForWin() || checkDiagonalsForWin());

    if (winner) {
        if (TicTacCollection.gatos.isEmpty()) {
            TicTacCollection.gatos.add(this);
        } else {
            TicTacCollection.gatos.add(this);
        }
    }
    return winner;
}

private boolean checkRowsForWin() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (checkRowCol(board[i][0].getText(), board[i][1].getText(), board[i][2].getText()) == true) {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}

private boolean checkColumnsForWin() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (checkRowCol(board[0][i].getText(), board[1][i].getText(), board[2][i].getText()) == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean checkDiagonalsForWin() {
    return ((checkRowCol(board[0][0].getText(), board[1][1].getText(), board[2][2].getText()) == true) || (checkRowCol(board[0][2].getText(), board[1][1].getText(), board[2][0].getText()) == true));
}

private boolean checkRowCol(String c1, String c2, String c3) {
    return ((c1.length() > 0) && (c1.equals(c2)) && (c2.equals(c3)));
}

public void setMarca(JButton boton) {
    if (currentPlayerMark == 'X') {
        boton.setText("X");
        currentPlayerMark = 'O';
    } else {
        currentPlayerMark = 'X';
        boton.setText("O");
    }

    if (checkForWin()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El ganador fue el jugador con la marca: " + boton.getText());

        System.out.println("EN GATO HAY " + TicTacCollection.gatos.size());
        if (TicTacCollection.gatos.size() == 4) {
            TicTacCollection.showMatches();
        }
        if (TicTacCollection.gatos.size() >= 1 && TicTacCollection.gatos.size() < 4) {

            otro = new Tablero();
            this.hide();
            otro.setVisible(true);
            otro.setTitle("otro tablero");
        }

    } else if (isBoardFull()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empate");
        reset();
    }

}
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //Código auto generado ...

 /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
Tablero tabla = new Tablero();
tabla.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

//Cada uno de los nueve botones tiene su `ActionPerformed` donde se invoca `setMarca(boton)`

private void b1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-  FIRST:event_b1ActionPerformed 
    setMarca(b1);
}//GEN-LAST:event_b1ActionPerformed
```

En esta clase se almacenan los tableros

```
public class TicTacCollection {
    public static ArrayList<Tablero> gatos = new ArrayList<Tablero>();    

    static int x =10,y=20;

    public ArrayList<Tablero> devuelveGatos(){
        return gatos;
    }

    public static void showMatches(){

        System.out.println("Estas son las partidas y los resultados");
        for (int i = 0; i < gatos.size(); i++) { 

            if(i != 0){
                gatos.get(i).setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            }
            gatos.get(i).setTitle("Gato"+i);
            gatos.get(i).setLocation(x,y);x+=286;
            gatos.get(i).setVisible(true);            
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente:

Tu tienes un campo `Tablero otro` en tu clase `Tablero`. Si tu pasas este `otro` al `ArrayList` en `TicTacCollection`, se pasa la **referencia** a este variable y se agrega a la lista. La próxima vez que se llama `checkForWin()`, este campo está sobre escrito con un nuevo `Tablero`, **también** afectando la referencia guardada en la lista.

Te recomiendo dar una vuelta y leer un poco sobre conceptos de programación orientado a objetos y luego empezar de nuevo desde cero. Como usas campos declarado como `static` en clases básicamente como variables globales arriesga confusión, y en cualquier proyecto más complejo te va causar puros dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Por favor, evitemos usar los resaltados en negrita y cursiva para código. Existe el battick (`) para resaltar código. Nombres de clases, métodos, variables, son código, usemos el resaltado apropiado.

Comment: pues tampoco supe que pasa si no le paso el `otro` y si el `this`

Comment: Si tu pasas `this` pasas una referencia al objeto mismo, pasando `otro` pasas una referencia a otra instancia de `Tablero` creado en `checkForWin()`. Para más detailles deberías compartir tu método `main` donde lanzas tu programa.